# Interpolating raster without edge bleeding in GDAL/Python

Tags: python, gdal, scipy

I'm working with a raster that is loaded into a numpy array that has a bit of noise in it. The area that I'm interested in is a particular area in the center of the image, but not necessarily bound by a rectangle.

I need to interpolate (smooth) out the "particular area", but not have the edges bleed in. I've tried using the SciPy Gaussian Filter, but that takes values outside of the area desired and averages that into the image.

Is there some way to tell SciPy 0 is the nodata value and to disregard it? or is there a way better way that I'm missing?